# How to set color of asterisk added by FieldTitle component for validation={required()} fields

Tags: react-admin

There seems to be no way of styling the asterisk that FieldTitle adds for components that have validation={required()} fields.
You can use an asterisk that mui provides for required fields by providing the "required" attribute, but you'll get just two asterisks.

React-admin v2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, react-admin provides no API to style the asterisk in its Input components.

You'll have to [build your own Input component](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#writing-your-own-input-component), as explained in the react-admin documentation:

```
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import { useInput, required } from 'react-admin';

const BoundedTextField = props => {
    const {
        input: { name, onChange, ...rest },
        meta: { touched, error },
        isRequired
    } = useInput(props);

    return (
        <TextField
            name={name}
            label={props.label}
            onChange={onChange}
            error={!!(touched && error)}
            helperText={touched && error}
            required={isRequired}
            {...rest}
        />
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you’re using `FormLabel` from Material-UI and you have to use it for selected fields, you can use with `required` and `MuiFormLabel-asterisk`.

```
<FormLabel required sx={{ '& .MuiFormLabel-asterisk': { color: '#FF0000' } }}>Title</FormLabel>
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that the question was related to RA v2. Now it’s possible to style it with ax indeed